# Is onLocationChanged thread safe?

Tags: android, multithreading, gps, thread-safety

Do i need to use a lock or is the android's method `onLocationChanged(Location loc)` for gps thread safe? I dn't want to have problem, but i don't know if it's already thread-safe because there is nothing in the android documentation about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onLocationChanged()` will be called on whatever thread is associated with the `Looper` you provided, or the main application thread if you did not provide a `Looper`.

Whether *your code* in `onLocationChanged()` is thread safe depends on what it does and what other threads in your app do.

IOW, method calls are not thread safe; code is thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

Since you provide the onLocationChanged() you are responsible if you need thread-saftey.
In doubt I would not write to the Location received, if you only read from it, there are no thread-saftey issues with that object.